# Можно ли использовать DLL (написанную на C#) на компьютере без .net framework

Tags: c#, dll

Я попытался использовать библиотеку [Unmanaged Exports (.NET DllExport)](https://github.com/3F/DllExport) в надежде что с ее помощью получится использовать свою `DLL` без `.net framework`.

Пример:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
[DllExport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static string Test(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string firstName, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lastName)
{
    return string.Format("Hello {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

Подключил свою `DLL` к программе на `Delphi`, но при вызове метода вышла ошибка что отсутствует `.net framework`

Насколько я понял моя `DLL` должна стать (unmanaged code) и работать без `.net framework`. Я прав, или я не до конца понимаю суть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код написанный на C# компилируются в промежуточный код IL для виртуальной машины .NET и может быть выполнен только ей. Поэтому когда вы запускаете свое приложение на другой машине, то она никаким образом не может выполнится без .NET фреймворка.

Если я правильно понял, библиотека Unmanaged Exports (.NET DllExport) выполняет всего лишь добавление имен для экспорта, но на сам код IL она не влияет. Поэтому ее использование никак не поможет запустить ее на машине без фреймворка.

Что бы данный подход сработал, надо заставить компилятор перевести IL код для виртуальной машины в нативный код для процессора. Мне не встречалась подобная функциональность, но [на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921656/compiling-c-sharp-to-native) пишут [про .NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx) который умеет это делать и включен в VS2015.

Comment: [ngen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx)